# Замена символов в заданных границах

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Помогите составить регулярное выражение -
замена символов `[` на символы `(` и `]` - на `)` в определенной границе при помощи регулярных выражений.

Например:

```
|link|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.torrent||poster|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_poster.jpg||year|2007||janr|Logic,Puzzle,3D,1stPerson||razrab|Valve Software||screens|[thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.jpg[/thumb][thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_2.jpg[/thumb]')
```

В данном примере нужно заменить символы `[` на символы `(` и `]` - на `)` только после слова `screens`.

И должно получиться следующее:

```
|link|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.torrent||poster|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_poster.jpg||year|2007||janr|Logic,Puzzle,3D,1stPerson||razrab|Valve Software||screens|(thumb)(r_g__mechanics)_portal_dilogy.jpg(/thumb)(thumb)(r_g__mechanics)_portal_dilogy_2.jpg(/thumb)')
```

Comment: @sergo-8ck, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Тут можно и без регулярного выражения обойтись, пример на PHP:

```
<?php

function replace_part ($src, $delimiter) {
    $part = explode($delimiter, $src, 2);
    if (is_array($part) and count($part) > 1) {
        $part[1] = str_replace(array('[',']'), array('(',')'), $part[1]);
        return implode($delimiter, $part);
    }
    return $src;
}

$delimiter = '|screens|';
$src  = "|link|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.torrent||poster|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_poster.jpg||year|2007||janr|Logic,Puzzle,3D,1stPerson||razrab|Valve Software||screens|[thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.jpg[/thumb][thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_2.jpg[/thumb]')";
$dst = replace_part($src, $delimiter);

echo "$src\n---\n$dst\n";
```

В результате получаем:

```
|link|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.torrent||poster|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_poster.jpg||year|2007||janr|Logic,Puzzle,3D,1stPerson||razrab|Valve Software||screens|[thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.jpg[/thumb][thumb][r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_2.jpg[/thumb]')
---
|link|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy.torrent||poster|[r_g__mechanics]_portal_dilogy_poster.jpg||year|2007||janr|Logic,Puzzle,3D,1stPerson||razrab|Valve Software||screens|(thumb)(r_g__mechanics)_portal_dilogy.jpg(/thumb)(thumb)(r_g__mechanics)_portal_dilogy_2.jpg(/thumb)')
```